# LINQ Group by with multiple values

Tags: linq, group-by

So I have a simple class `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    internal int PersonID;
    internal string car;
    internal int count;
}
```

and I want to group by the `PersonID`, so that I get a List of all Cars and a sum of all counts:

```
public class Result
{
    public int PersonID;
    public List<string> cars;
    public int sum;
}
```

I know how to group and create the summation:

```
var sums = from foo in persons
       group foo by foo.PersonID into groupings

       select new Result
       {
           PersonID = groupings.Key,               
           sum = groupings.Sum(g => g.count)
       };
```

But how can I create the list of cars into the `Result`?

Comment: Common sense says that `PersonID` should be unique, so how do you get a list of strings for one id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be one example with `anonymous class` but should be the same with the `Result`:

```
List<Person> p = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {PersonID = 1, car = "Audo", count = 1},
    new Person {PersonID = 1, car = "Bmw", count = 2},
    new Person {PersonID = 1, car = "Reno", count = 3},
    new Person {PersonID = 2, car = "Audi", count = 1},
    new Person {PersonID = 3, car = "Audi", count = 1},
};

var res = p.GroupBy(i => i.PersonID).Select(g =>
    new {
            ID = g.Key, 
            Cars = g.Select(_ => _.car).ToList(), 
            Count = g.Sum(_ => _.count)
    });
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!